# Google Chrome - Fieldset Overflow Bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Google Chrome seems to have a bug when overflowing content inside of a fieldset.

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Dismissile/Lnm42/

If you look at the page, you will see that when you have a container inside of a fieldset, and the container has `overflow: auto` set, and that container has content that will overflow horizontally, the fieldset actually expands instead of using a scrollbar:

```
<fieldset class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">
            asdf
        </div>
     </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">
            asdf
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.grandchild {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 2000px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Is there a CSS hack/fix I can use so that content overflows properly when inside a fieldset in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using JavaScript to set the width of the viewport:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/Lnm42/2/

I added a class called `fieldset-width` to the fieldset:

`<fieldset class="parent fieldset-width">`

Then added this JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fieldset-width").css("width", $(window).width() - 82);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".fieldset-width").css("width", $(window).width() - 82);
});
```

*My only comment is that I can't think of a good reason to interfere with the default fieldset functionality.  I dislike "scroll bars within scroll bars" to begin with.  For input fields, which fieldsets usually surround, I would be especially cautious about making the user scroll around to get to all the input fields.*

Comment: Yeah don't mess with fieldset functionality via JS, for one thing you have that arbitrary 82px in there plus your resize handler may run slow on pages with heavy DOMs since it's not throttled. Use `min-width: auto` instead to fix this issue (Chrome uses `-webkit-min-content` by default), to verify this right-click on fieldset element and use "inspect element" and view "computed style" then note the "min-width" property defined in user agent stylesheet.

Comment: **UPDATE:** `min-width: auto` no longer works. Use `min-width: inherit` instead. See my suggested answer for details.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE:**

As of a recent Chrome for MS Windows update (v28 maybe? Haven't tracked it down yet), `auto` is no longer a valid value for `min-width`, and this solution no longer works!

**New solution:**

Using `inherit` instead of `auto` appears to fix the issue for all cases I have tested so far. (Including the original fiddle.. see [the new fiddle fix](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnm42/50/) for details.)

The updated fix: `FIELDSET {min-width: inherit; }`

**Original answer:**

Chrome defines for `fieldset` the default user agent style: `min-width: -webkit-min-content`.

So when your viewable area (aka "screen") is smaller than your `div` with specific width, the `-webkit-min-content` grows the fieldset to accommodate the size of the contents (plus padding, etc.).

The fix: `FIELDSET { min-width: auto; }`

I fixed your fiddle, [try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnm42/48/)!

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: This helped so much, thanks! Just wanted to add if you want to cut off the content inside of the fieldset, you can add `overflow: auto;` but this may not be the best approach in all situations as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pseudo fieldset (aka `<div class="fieldset"></div>`) I believe you can get close. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsolesimonsen/V6Tkw/5/).

Try this styling:

```
fieldset,.fieldset {
   margin: 10px;
   border: solid 1px black;
   position: relative;
   padding: .5em;
}

.legend {
   left: 0.5em;
   top: -0.6em;
   color: black;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 0 0.25em 0 0.25em;
}
```

It is less than ideal as fieldset styling needs to be duplicated, but for me it was the only tolerable solution to my run-in with this problem that I have been able to come up with. As above you may be able to apply your existing fieldset styling to the pseudo one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fieldset {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is your example with fix: http://jsfiddle.net/2u3a9goc/

Answer (score 0):

You can add style="display:table-column;" to the fieldset as a workaround.