# Overflow of div inside fieldset not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

What's going on here, is this a bug in Chrome?

When I introduce a `fieldset`, overflow of the nested `div` stops working in Chrome.

[image: Chrome vs IE]

Here is a minimal example.

```
html
head
    style(type="text/css").
        .wrapper {
            overflow: scroll;
            height: 100px;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        fieldset {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }

body
    form
        .wrapper
            .content aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddd
    form
        fieldset
            .wrapper
                .content aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadsssssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

<strike>I've tested various suggested workarounds from [Google Chrome - Fieldset Overflow Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084343/google-chrome-fieldset-overflow-bug), but it's not working for me.</strike>

Turns out the `min-width: inherit` workaround does in fact work..

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify `overflow-x` to your code. Also please add a `width` to your code. Once you add both of those it should overflow properly :)

*If there is no width, how will it know what to overflow?*

Comment: Turns out one of the workarounds does indeed work (see edit). Your workaround however does not (even when explicitily setting a width).

Comment: Good :) At least you figured it out! :D (With a little of my help right? lol)